# Javascript: Read Text File using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, marquee

Can't get AJAX to work! I have a marquee on a website, got it working! But I want it to find the text of the marquee in a text file, and I want it to read the text in the text file (which is one line) and assign it to the variable called `content`, which is a global variable in the script tag.

When I run the website (local IIS), the marquee text is: "undefined" (without the quotes).

Why isn't it assigning the text to the variable `content`?

```
    var content

    function loadXMLDoc()
    {   
        var textfile;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { 
            textfile = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        textfile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {   
            if (textfile.readyState == 4 && textfile.status == 200)
            { 
                content = textfile.responseText; 
            }
        }
        textfile.open("GET", "C:\Users\Fares\Dropbox\Sync\College\Computing\DeltaOne\MarqueeText.txt", true);
        textfile.send();
    }
```

**EDIT:** A million thanks to @kuncajs, as he pointed out I forgot to call the function! :) Fixed! Thanks to everyone else!

Comment: Thanks @BLSully for the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use local paths like:
`C:\Users\Fares\Dropbox\Sync\College\Computing\DeltaOne\MarqueeText.txt`

Place it in the www directory of your IIS and state the path like:
`localhost/text.txt`

The server can have restricted access to your filesystem and also you should try relative paths like `text.txt` or absolute paths `/text.txt` so the paths work even when you deploy it in the production environment.

**EDIT:**
So if this did not help then make sure that you really call the `loadXMLDoc()` function. Also check that everything you do is *after* the AJAX ends! I mean you do the assignment in the if - when AJAX is done but you should also initialize your marquee !AFTER! the text is loaded. If you do it before it will be undefined

Comment: Hiya! Thanks @kuncajs! Just did as you told me, still got "undefined" in the marquee box unfortunately. I tried also removing "localhost/" and keeping just the text file name. The text file is in the root folder of the www.

Comment: OK, it works for me: I have got `textfile.open("GET", "text.txt", true);` the files text.txt is in the same directory as my html file with JS. Are you sure you are really calling `loadXMLDoc()` somewhere in your code - i mean executing the function?

Comment: Ah! You're right @kuncajs I forgot to call the function! It's working now, thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative or absolute path first.

If that doesn't work check that when using your browser you can access the file (let's say your website is on `mysite.com/index.html`, try opening `mysite.com/text.txt`)

If you can't access it using your browser then you will have to configure your server to allow this file to be read, never tried IIS so I can't help you there.

Also since you are asking your XHR to be asynchronous it might take a little time before the variable is populated (depending on your/your server's speed)