# using ajax to get local text file content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 files named `index.html` and `mytext.txt` in the same folder. I want to get contents of `mytext.txt` using an ajax call in the `index.html`. I use this code but it is only working in firefox not chrome:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mytext.txt",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I am opening index.html simply from explorer not server!

Comment: then why have you named the text file as folders.txt?

Comment: You need a webserver to do that. You can't run AJAX without it.

Comment: @putvande, why would OP need a webserver for that?

Comment: Using the `file://` protocol is not allowed with ajax calls.  It *needs* to be on a webserver, even if that webserver is `http://localhost`

Comment: @Amit Joki, sorry my mistake when typing here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading local files with Javascript without a web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902538/loading-local-files-with-javascript-without-a-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to start a webserver for this to work in chrome due to cross origin policy

Comment: How would you say cross origin policy !

Answer (score 0):

Refer

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469111/how-to-read-contents-of-a-file-using-javascript)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547407/javascript-read-text-file-using-ajax)

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
   createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("/home");
```