# HTML - read .txt file from URL location in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read a .txt file an URL location, lets say from http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt and process its content on my page.

Can you point me out some tutorials or some basic code on how to do this in javascript?

I have a basic HTML code where I have some tables and I want to populate them with text from a .txt from a given URL location, but I do not know how to read the data from that location.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pseudoganglia Interface</title>
  <!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
  <style type="text/css">
  table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table.gridtable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
  }
  table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  </style>
  <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
  <script>
    function getText()
    {
     // read text from URL location
    }
    function populateTables() {
      var tableHP = document.getElementById("tHP");
      // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
      var row = tableHP.insertRow(tableHP.rows.length);
      // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

      // Add some text to the new cells:
      cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
      cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="populateTables()">
<table class="gridtable" id="tHP">
  <tr>
<th colspan=2>HP</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td># SN</td>
<td>% of used RAM</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table class="gridtable" id="tIBM">
  <tr>
<th colspan=2>IBM</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td># CN</td>
<td>% of used RAM</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have control over the location which has this text file?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is Ajax. The world doesn't need another Ajax tutorial (so voting to close as too broad).

Comment: It's not too broad at all, it's just duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547407/javascript-read-text-file-using-ajax

Comment: @CyberDude — It doesn't look like a duplicate of that one, since the question has already found the XHR object and tried to use it.

Comment: Maybe not 100%, there are plenty of similar questions, I just picked one.

Comment: I looked at about a dozen and couldn't find any I thought were actual duplicates of this one.

Comment: I have tried the solution from the post mentioned by @CyberDude , however it's not working. It's not going inside this if `if (textfile.readyState == 4 && textfile.status == 200)` . Does it have something to do with Access-Control-Allow-Origin ? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: The value of `textfile.readyState` is set to the value of `4` and `textfile.status` is set to the value of `0`.

Comment: @Simon — If it had something to do with Access-Control-Allow-Origin then you'd get an error message saying so.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all.  As I read it, the asker is looking for a simple way to read a text file from a URL - say, something like std.file.read in D or File.ReadAllText in .NET, or a file I/O (or just I) API similar to those found in most programming languages, but which uses a URL as an input source.

Comment: Another idea, which maybe the asker was hoping exists, is a means of accessing the content of a file referenced in a <link> tag from JavaScript.  Loading the file would then be part of the process of loading the page, just like loading an image, JS file or CSS file is.  In any case, this question isn't asking how to use a specific method for reading a file, thus isn't a duplicate of any question that is.  Rather, the essence is one of "what approaches exist?".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

this code may help you:

```js
function getText(){
    // read text from URL location
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt', true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
                return request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
}
function populateTables(){
    
    var outer_text = getText();
    outer_text = outer_text.split('\n');    // you can adjust the manner of parsing the received file (regexp)
    
    var tableHP = document.getElementById("tHP");
// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
    var row = tableHP.insertRow(tableHP.rows.length);
// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = outer_text[0];
    cell2.innerHTML = outer_text[1];
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as above. For `request.readyState` I get the value of `4` and for `request.status` I get the value of `0`. Do you know what might cause this and how should I fix it?

Comment: And for `var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');` I get `null`.

Comment: Probably, you don't have permissions to request resources from another domain (ES same origin policy). On "that" domain the following header should be set: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: I realize this is an old question now, but it was helpful to me so I'll add my observation as to why some may be having problems with it. The call to request.open includes `true` for asynchronous but the getText() function is being called with the assumption that the result will be present immediately. In my case, I called a separate function with  request.responseText rather than returning it. Maybe passing false to request.open() might block until it's loaded. That could be an alternative fix.

Answer (score 24):

from [codegrepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/javascript+call+to+read+text+file+from+url) using fetch (unsupported on IE).

```js
const url = "http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt"
fetch(url)
   .then( r => r.text() )
   .then( t => //process your text! )
```

Comment: Clean and does the job

Comment: More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_fetch.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: On the status of the Fetch API, this might be of interest: https://caniuse.com/fetch