# Can you get the content of a github file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to get the content of a text file (txt/jss/html/...) with javascript or any other way, inserting it to a variable? (Also jquery is ok)
I mean:
abc.txt contains some text, that ttext should be stored into a variable.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this might help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828029/html-read-txt-file-from-url-location-in-javascript

Comment: @John it does not work, it outputs 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty straightforward all you have to do is change the string a little bit like so, for example here is json file from a github repo

https://github.com/arnav7633/tej.js/blob/main/tsconfig.json

now that string gets changed to

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arnav7633/tej.js/main/tsconfig.json

The domain changes. Then make a simple axios/fetch query to that URL
[image]

```js
(async() => {
const res = await axios.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arnav7633/tej.js/main/tsconfig.json")
console.log(res.data)
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thats kinda what i was searching for, but is there a way to do it from javascript? curl is not a js function.

Comment: I was just demonstrating that changing the domain works, it would result in the same response from any library be it curl or axios @Xarber

Comment: I mean, changing the domain is ok, but i want to get the content of the page inside a variable, so it can be used later. What i got into is the fetch function, but most times it returns undefined or null. Is there any other way?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet it loads fine, can you show me the link you tried? @Xarber

Comment: Nevermind, now it works. I found a js bug: If you save the fetch results in localStorage when you get it sometimes it could bug and give you the same result twice. I mean:
put fetch in a function;
I Call fetch
fetch returns 'hi' > Save 'hi' in localStorage
Insert LocalStorage to a var
var = 'hi';
I Call fetch on a different link
fetch returns 'hi2' > Save 'hi2' in localStorage
Insert LocalStorage to a var
var = 'hi';
That was my problem so i just put all of the code inside the fetch 'then' function and now it works. Still thanks for the raw github link.

Comment: Oh cool didn'know this worked too, thanks